# Displaying the result of $sum from MongoDB query on a Node JS Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking to display the results of a Mongo query on a Javascript web page with the aid of a Node Js server. I am using an aggregate pipeline to sum a field on certain conditions. I can get the proper results of the query, however, when I try to display it on the page it only says [object Object]. The query is as follows:

```
    function(callback) {
        Player.aggregate([{
            $match: {$and: [
                {isOwned: user.id},{active: 1}]},
            },{
                $group: { _id: "$isOwned",
                total: {
                    $sum: "$weekPts"
                }
            }
        }],
        function (err,result){
            if (err) return callback(err);
            oppPoints = result;
            callback();
        });
    }
```

The results of the query in the console are:

```
[ { _id: '5bf0362ac7fb1612e035f000', total: 100.04 } ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It seems so simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: could you share the code where you use this function? most likely you should `JSON.stringify()` your result object so that it doesn't show as an object but a string instead

Comment: something like `oppPoints = JSON.stringify(result)`. It really depends on how you want to display the data. Do you want to display just some properties? the entire object?

Comment: The function is called as part of a get request to display a web page. the "oppPoints" variable is used within the rendering like : res.render('matchup.handlebars', {oPoints : oppPoints}); along with a few other variables.

Comment: I really just want to display 100.04, I won't need anything else.

Comment: then do this: `oppPoints = result[0].total`

Comment: or this: `res.render('matchup.handlebars', {oPoints : oppPoints[0].total})`

Comment: Fantastic that worked perfectly. Much appreciated!